# How to set large text to hint in textinputlayout dynamically?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to set large text to hint in **Textinputlayout** android. But, after some text its showing **"..."**. After I getting this I tried **"\n"** inside text. Its working fine but I want to implement **dynamically**. could you please give any solution for this..?

Comment: add your code for try to

Comment: can you share your xml

Comment: is there any specific reason to use large text as hints should be short and precise.

Answer (score 0):

your Question is not clear.I understood like this.

case 1: if you try to show full text hint in **Textinputlayout** then you can do like this

add this like in **Textinputlayout**

```
app:counterEnabled="true"
app:counterMaxLength="420"
```

case 2: if you added these two lines in your **Textinputlayout** then remove these two lines.

```
 android:ellipsize="end" 
    android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: I want to set large text to hint(goes upside when user click on editbox) not for input value